# C# database update overlap

Tags: c#, sql, list, ms-access

I have 2 lists, both containing integers that represent ratings of players in their respective team.

```
Ex:
team1ListOfRatings: 9,1,4
team2ListOfRatings: 6,2,4
```

I wish to enter these into an access database that I have. However, when I try to enter them,  if there are any similarities with the numbers in the lists (in the example shown above, this is '4') then the duplicate rating in the first list will be allocated to team 2 in the database.

It would produce this result:

```
Players in team 1: Ben (rating 9), Will(rating 1) 
Players in team 2: Philip(rating 6), Sam(rating 2), Bert(rating 4), Gary(rating 4)
```

From the example you can see above, it is obvious that Gary needs to be in the first team, however because I use a for loop it reallocates any duplicates to the team that was used in the most recent for loop.
Here is the code that I use for this:

```
// this adds the players to the database temporarily without a team
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++)
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(CONNECTION STRING HERE);

    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

    connection.Open();
    command.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = textBox[i].Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@rating", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ratingBox[i].Text);
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TotalPlayerName ([PlayerName], [Team], [Rating],  [Substitute], [Complete], [SportID]) VALUES (@name, null , @rating,  false, false, " + ID + ")";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.Connection = connection;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}


            //list of all ratings:

            List<int> ratingList = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++)
            {
                ratingList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(ratingBox[i].Text));
            }
            ratingList.Sort();
            var count = ratingList.Count();

            // if even number of players, keep aside the one in the middle (as rating)
            int? middle = null;
            if (count % 2 != 0)
            {
                middle = ratingList[count / 2];
                ratingList.RemoveAt(count / 2);
            }

            var ratingListDesc = ratingList.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToList();

            var half = count / 2;
            var take = half % 2 != 0 ? half - 1 : half;

            var team1List = ratingList.Take(take).Where((r, i) => i % 2 == 0).ToList();
            team1List.AddRange(ratingListDesc.Take(take).Where((r, i) => i % 2 == 0));

            var team2List = ratingList.Take(take).Where((r, i) => i % 2 != 0).ToList();
            team2List.AddRange(ratingListDesc.Take(take).Where((r, i) => i % 2 != 0));

            // we just have to redistribute the remaining pair between each team
            if (half % 2 != 0)
            {
                team1List.Add(ratingList[half - 1]);
                team2List.Add(ratingListDesc[half - 1]);
            }

            // this part will add the team numbers to the database
            for (int i = 0; i < (count/2); i++)
            {
                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(CONNECTION STRING HERE);

                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

                connection.Open();
                command.CommandText = "update TotalPlayerName set Team = 1, Complete = true WHERE Team = null AND Complete = false AND Rating = " + team1List[i];
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Connection = connection;

                command.ExecuteScalar();
                command.CommandText = "update TotalPlayerName set Team = 2, Complete = true WHERE Team = null AND Complete = false AND Rating = " + team2List[i];
                command.ExecuteScalar();
                connection.Close();


            }
```

Is there any way to avoid this and add the ratings without them overlapping?

NB: The code is here just as an example of what I am doing, you don't have to read it to get the idea of what I'm trying to do but it may or may not help you to understand.

Comment: why don't you create a class that represents what you are trying to do and then create a `List<T>` of that class..this way you won't have any overlapping or you can create a new Dictionary<string, int> I think that you are going about this the hard way.. personally speaking..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately this is one of the first projects that I've worked on so im not too sure what you mean

Comment: I have given you the key words / terms to execute an effective google search `DataGridView Template, Binding datatable to DataGridView, executing Sql Query in C#,etc..` there are tons of working examples out there first project or not if you do not know how to make a List<T> meaning a List<Class> object  do a google search also if there are tons of excellent C# for beginner tutorials online for free.. you need to understand the basics before jumping into something that's more complex in nature based on your current programming level..respectfully

Comment: I would also recommend that you start using the debugger too.. if you do not understand the code that you are writing in regard to debugging then you are really wasting your time because even if someone provided you with a working solution, how would you understand it if you had to maintain it or make changes post getting a solution from a debugging standpoint..

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies both in the fact that there is duplicate information, and that information is in the same location in each list.  If you break between your SQL inserts, and query the DB to look at the data, I expect you would find that your where clause evaluates true for that particular player on both inserts.

In regards to what edits to make to change it, I would recommend dividing your lists of players into lists, one for team 1 and the other for team 2, and running the update query for team 1 ONLY on the team 1 list, and the same for team 2.

A few notes.. You have a lot of opportunities for integer division bugs in the above listed code, or getting players from 1 team transferred into the other team.  I can't exactly provide you a piece of code to fix your problem without rewriting a significant portion of the code snippet.  I would also recommend fully constructing your database row entries and inserting them all at one time, rather than inserting, and then going back and updating.  It adds unneeded load on the database, and introduces another layer of possible errors.

My understanding of the code is as follows:

1. Combine player ratings
2. If odd players, remove middle rating
3. Divide players amongst teams such that top rating team 1, second top rating team 2, third top rating team 1 etc etc
4. Save data to DB.

The following may be a way of doing that, and avoiding a lot of the possible sources of error.

```
List<int> ratingsList = new List<int>(); //Presume this is already populated.
List<int> team1 = new List<int>();
List<int> team2 = new List<int>();

ratingsList = ratingsList.Sort();

if(ratingsList.Count() % 2 != 0)
{
    ratingsList.Remove((ratingsList.Count()/2)+2));  //Integer divide intentional
}

for(int i = 0; i < ratingsList.Count() ; i++)
{
    if(i%2 != 0)
    {
        team1.Add(ratingsList[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        team2.Add(ratingsList[i]);
    }
}

foreach(var player in team1)
{
    //Add SQL Insert here
}
foreach(var player in team2)
{
    //Add SQL Insert here
}
```

The above listed snippet is pseudo-code, so don't expect it to just work.  The biggest problem that I see, is that players are being divided and identified by rating, which is not exclusive to a single player, so you have no way of uniquely identifying players in the code.  Suggestion beyond the purview of the question would be to build a player class to contain the information, and make ratingsList, team1, team2 of type Player.  You can still use OrderByDesc (linq) to order by the rating, and then you don't have to worry about keeping track of what value is assigned to who.